# Magento - create table store, retrieve and display in grid

Tags: php, magento

How to create a new module for listing developer table in magento backend?

I need to create, insert, update and select data to magento backend grid from  customized table.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am posting to use very good admin backend extension

Just go throw [this tutorial](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/26/admin-part1-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs/) and understand carefully

just change your table name and column name as you need to display your developer table

hope it will useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module creator to achieve this. There are a few out there.

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html - this one is mine :). It let's you create your entities in a similar way you create a table using phpmyadmin
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/modulecreator.html - this is a minimalist module creator, very good for learning purposes.
- http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/ - this is a pretty complex one and it has the advantage of being online, so you don't have to install any extension.